# Change a ListView image item's source when selected

Tags: wpf, image, listview, styles

Below is a sample of what I am after:

[image: The paging indicator I would like to reproduce]

I have decided to implement that using a ListView (tried a custom control based on Selector but I could not managed to output anything satisfying).

My list displays fine but I am struggling to find how to change the image source when the item gets selected. Here is my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PagingIndicatorTemplate">
        <Image Width="20" Height="20">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/MyProject;component/Resources/Images/ic_paging_button_normal.png" />
                <!-- I guess that's where I need to put my stuff to change the image ? ... -->
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

    <ListView Name="PagingIndicator" 
              Height="30" 
              ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PagingIndicatorTemplate}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=News}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Where from you loading image source? Does item contains an image source path or this is a static resources data?

Comment: My idea is to store all image paths in Resources Collection array and then bind it to ListView SelectedItemIndex like Source="{Binding ImageSources[SelectedItemIndex], Mode=Default}"

Comment: I am loading the images from a path like: /MyProject;component/Resources/Images/ic_paging_button_normal.png

Comment: Basically yu have two different images for each list item? You ca add DataTrigger and update Source property depends on data item state or even SelectedIndex of list

Comment: How would you do that? (I'm quite new to WPF) Also, data item state cannot be modified to contain a "IsSelected" property, the only option would be to be based on the SelectedIndex of the list for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to solve the problem like that:

- Make two different item templates (each with their own images, styles for mouse over, mouse pressed, ...)
- Change the Template property of the ListViewItem with a trigger on its IsSelected property.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is one thing wrong... you are using `ListView` but targetting style to `ListBoxItem`. It should be `ListViewItem`.
2. In `Image`'s style use a DataTrigger where check the binding on `RelativeSource` `ListViewItem` and `Path=IsSelected` (if its True) and change the `Source` of the image.